# Java Middleware in Hoverfly Rule

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing

I'm trying to use hoverfly java and want to set the middleware in my test.

```
@ClassRule
    public static HoverflyRule hoverflyRule = HoverflyRule.inCaptureOrSimulationMode(("abc.json"), HoverflyConfig.configs().remote().host("localhost").adminPort(8888).proxyPort(8500));
```

How can I update my rule to set the middleware file?

Comment: What problems do you experience? Have you read the spec? https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/hoverfly-java/latest/hoverfly-java.pdf ...File is relative to src/test/resources/hoverfly...

Comment: I don't think they support java middleware yet